# Get data from database, and show it in a TextBox on another form

Tags: c#, sql

Just so you are all aware, I have almost solved the issue BUT there is a key item in my way.

Alright. I have a "DataModule" class where there are several DataAdaptors, my DataSet, and the Connection.

My database is working fine, and so is saving and retrieving (including updating and deleting) data. If I put a TextBox on the DataModule form, and use an OleDbReader, and the following statement: txtBoxTest.Text = reader["firstName"].ToString();

Then the selected record's (which I have chosen by ID number) first name appears in the box.

However, the ACTUAL place for this data to appear is on another form, and as we know, components on a Windows Forms Application are set to "private", by default. Thus, my dilemma.

**Question is below this line**

How can I make the data appear in the correct form's TextBoxes (which is PatientRecord.cs) using the DataModule class' reader, and the statement of code I provided?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**There are Some way for Data transfer between forms.I explain one of common ways:**

> Sender form:

```
 FrmChild child = new FrmChild(number,line,this.Width);
            child.Owner = this;

            child.Show();
```

> Receiver form:

```
public partial class FrmChild : Form
    {

        int frmw;//A public varaible

        public FrmChild()//normal constrauctor
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        } 

        public FrmChild(String cNumber,byte LINE,int w)//custom constrauctor
        {

            frmw = w;
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am not sure how this will help me, given how I have explained my situation above.

Comment: Which part of the PatientRecord class would you like me to put up? It's over 1600 lines long, see.